# CosmosDB Emulator - Losing data after deleting Docker Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-cosmosdb, docker-volume, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

I am building a `CosmosDB Emulator` container via a `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  cosmosdb:
    container_name: cosmosdb
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator:latest"
    tty: true
    mem_limit: 2G
    cpu_count: 2
    environment:
      - AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_PARTITION_COUNT=10
      - AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_ENABLE_DATA_PERSISTENCE=true
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
      #- '8900:8900'
      #- '8901:8901'
      #- '8902:8902'
      #- '10250:10250'
      #- '10251:10251'
      #- '10252:10252'
      #- '10253:10253'
      #- '10254:10254'
      #- '10255:10255'
      #- '10256:10256'
      #- '10350:10350'
    volumes:
       - vol_cosmos:/data/db

volumes: 
  vol_cosmos:
```

I then generate some data in it via the `CosmosDB Emulator Explorer`. However, if I delete the `container` I lose all the data, even though the `container` uses the specified `volume`, and the `volume` is not deleted ever.

Either I don't understand how `volumes` work, or something else is wrong, but I am looking for a way to persists the data even after deleting the `container`. A new one should just use the `volume` with the specified name if it exists, or create a new one if it doesn't, right?

The data stays intact after `container` and/or OS restarts. It just doesn't persist after deleting the `container`.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm running into this exact issue and struggling to figure out why my data gets wiped out each time.  Defeats the purpose of mounting a volume if the data is going to be destroyed each time the container is started.